# In Excel VBA, how could I compute sum of values which has a total limit that should not exceed $500, and then get corresponding product combination?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with two Columns Product and Price($).

| Product | Price($) |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 400 |
| C | 350 |
| D | 50 |
| E | 515 |
| F | 140 |

I am trying to use vba to get combination of value of all products that will not exceed $500. I have been trying with this code and I am not sure how to proceed from this point on.

```
Sub getCombination()
    Dim price As Long
    Dim limit As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim combination As String
        
    limit = 500
    combination = ""
    Range("B2").Activate
    price = Range("B2").Value
        
    For i = 1 To 6
        For j = 1 To 6
            If price <= limit Then
                price = price + ActiveCell.Offset(j, 0).Value
                combination = combination & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value & "," & ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    MsgBox combination

End Sub
```

My Expected output is something like
A,B
A,C
A,C,D
B,D
C,F
A,D
C,D
(Please note: Not All output combinations are specified here!)

How should I proceed with the existing code? Or do I really have a better way for me to implement this?

Comment: do you include single items?  or does it always have to be a group.  For example all but E by themselves match the requirement.

Comment: Also, you list `A,C` and `A,C,D` as expected, but not `A,D` and `C,D`.  Why not?  You need a clear definition of what is an acceptable combination.

Comment: Set it up with the solver, no need for vba. Add a column for binary and sumproduct for the total then a constraint that the sum is less or equal to 500.

Comment: Thank you @chrisneilsen for pointing it out. I know I have not listed all the output combination. I have listed only a few combination. I will update them

Comment: You can also do a cross join in Power Query. (See https://exceleratorbi.com.au/cross-join-with-power-query/) Then just create a total column and apply your 500 limit using a filter.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, I tried the solver, which is really great. Thank you.
Thank you Bryan. I will try it out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the item can be used or not, that is a binary response.  Using a binary number with the same number of digits as the number of items we can do all the combinations and do the testing:

```
Sub getCombination()
    
    Dim rngArr As Variant
    rngArr = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B7")
    
    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = 2 ^ UBound(rngArr, 1) - 1
    
    Dim OutArray As Variant
    ReDim OutArray(1 To cnt, 1 To 2)
    
    Dim k As Long
    k = 1
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To cnt
        Dim bin As String
        bin = Application.Dec2Bin(i, UBound(rngArr, 1))
        
        Dim delim As String
        delim = ""
        
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To UBound(rngArr, 1)
            If Mid(bin, j, 1) = "1" Then
                OutArray(k, 1) = OutArray(k, 1) & delim & rngArr(j, 1)
                delim = ", "
                OutArray(k, 2) = OutArray(k, 2) + rngArr(j, 2)
            End If
        Next j
        If OutArray(k, 2) <= 500 Then
            k = k + 1
        Else
            OutArray(k, 1) = ""
            OutArray(k, 2) = 0
        End If
    Next i
    
    Dim fnlarr As Variant
    ReDim fnlarr(1 To k - 1)
    
    For i = 1 To k - 1
        fnlarr(i) = OutArray(i, 1)
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print Join(fnlarr, " | ")

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This gives me a great idea